# Xamarin.iOSのメモリ確保について

Tags: ios, c#, iphone, xamarin

1週間程度連続で稼動させる前提のiOSアプリを開発しているのですが、
3日程度で落ちてしまいます。

原因はメモリリークということは分かっており、
取り急ぎメモリ確保（ヒープ領域サイズ拡大）を行いたいのですが、
Xamarin.iOSでも可能なのでしょうか？

ヒープサイズ（メモリ領域）は
　機種毎に異なる？（例えば新型iPadのほうが良い？）
　そもそも固定値？

Xamarin.Androidではプロジェクトの設定からヒープ領域のサイズを変更できるそうですが、
iOSでも同じようなことができると非常に助かります。

無知ですみませんが、
何卒、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/127540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369670/7258193

iOS では基本的に OS がメモリを管理しているため、ヒープサイズの拡張などは不可能なようです。
ただし、Xamarin の場合 C# を利用しているかと思いますので、`GC.Collect();` などを利用することで未使用のメモリを開放することが可能かと思います。

その他、即時必要のないメモリをストレージに移動させるなど、根本的な対処を行ったほうがよいかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。そうですよね。。